# starts logging when the limits are hit

Tags: linux, logs, monitoring, limit

`/etc/security/limits.conf`. The file is responsible to limit resources of users/groups on a Linux server. Unfortunately, the file does not generate any logs (or the case could be that I do not really know of them). So how can I hack it (not necessary internally) so that it starts logging when the limits are hit. Preferrably if it can send an email

Comment: limits.conf contains the limits. It just exists so that other processes can read from it. To be able to log you will need to figure out the current utilization of the resource. Which limit are you trying to log?

Comment: @shshank it can be any resource.What my problem is that i am running a Linux server and when it gets overloaded with requests ,the users get a error message .So i just want to notify myself about it when that happens.So with regards to that can you suggest me something

Comment: What is the server you are running? apache? nginx?

Comment: @shshank its nginx

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments on the question, you want something to monitor NginX and get notified on server overload.

For a more sophisticated approach you can Try Nagios. You can find some quickstart instructions [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart.html). It can provide you various stats, also a web interface, etc.

**Another way would be to read from the nginx error log.**

Locate the Nginx error log file.

Write a python script to read the error log every 1 minute or so.

If it encounters a new error or an error with the specific error code (e.g. >500), it can notify you.

**How to get Notified?**

Here you can get creative and implement several options:

Use the twitter API, make a twitter account for your Monitoring service with private timeline. Use the API calls to tweet mentioning you with the error code and time.

You can use the gmail API, to send a mail when error occurs.

Hope that helps.